# Unity prefab size

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I write simple 2D cell game. In this game the player can walk from one cell to another. I set quads in the unity graphis editor. But for player walk i need size of this quad for the same steps exactly cells.

1) I need aize of my prefab "green_quad".

2) Or any idea for same steps exactly cells for player.

I need like this chess or checkers desk.

I tried this:

```
GameObject Quad;
Quad = GameObject.Find ("green_quad");
SizeX = 0;
SizeY = 0;
SizeX = Quad.renderer.bounds.size.x;
SizeY = Quad.renderer.bounds.size.y;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert, but first of all, I would change the variable name "Quad" to something else.

And you should try to make it public and add it in the inspector, the `Find` function is a bit slow. If you can't that's okey, I guess.

If you can't get the renderer size, you could try using `collider.size` , creating a box collider for the quad.

```
BoxCollider quadCollider;
quadCollider = GameObject.Find ("green_quad").GetComponent<BoxCollider> ();
SizeX = 0;
SizeY = 0;
SizeX = quadCollider.size.x;
SizeY = quadCollider.size.y;
```

Keep in mind that, as I said, `Find` and `GetComponent` are a bit CPU intensive.